# Relieving letter

Tags: new-job, work-experience, india, relieving-letter

I worked for an IT company for 2 years and was very loyal in 2014. During my tenure at the company, the CEO did not prove my incentives. I thought this was the first time and I let it go. But the incentives were not paid for the last 11 months. Because of this, I left the company breaking the bond which was due in 1 month.

Now I am applying for another job for which I require a relieving letter from the previous company, but they do not answer my requests for this. What should I do?

I have copies of incentives here the company have cheated me on.

I do not want to get into legal things, and want to get my relieving letter happily.

Comment: You walked away from the company, "breaking the bond" - why would the company issue you a relieving letter in those circumstances?  And I am talking regardless of the reasons you left - those are your reasons, not the companies, so you haven't been "relieved", you simply left.  You need to get a lawyer involved to sort this out, as having read around I think that is the only way to force a company to issue a relieving letter.

Comment: If they also owe you money from 11 months, plus you'll need a relieving letter, isn't this a good reason to get a lawyer involved? You said you don't want to get into legal things, but...

Comment: On second look, that particular question isn't that great, but there are a [large number of questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relieving-letter?sort=votes&pageSize=15) relating to not having a relieving letter. One of them should certainly help answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

> I left the company breaking the bond which was due in 1 month.

This is where you made the mistake. As mentioned by @Moo, in the comments, the company is not obliged to issue you anything let alone relieving or experience letters.

> Now I am applying for another job and were I require relieving letter of that company, but they are not answering me on the same.

In India, IT companies generally ask for relieving letters, not because they want to a maintain a file containing all the documents of each employee. It is generally for the BGC(Background Verification Check) purposes. Even if you submit a letter, they would go back to the company and verify your claims with them.

> I have copies of incentives here the company have cheated on me...

You have some documentary proof that you worked in that company, that's good! Assuming you also have your old salary slips, you could use these documents to prove your association(& experience) with your old organization.

> I do not want to get into legal things

Although legal advice is off-topic here and considering the legal system in India, I would say that you won't stand a chance if you went to court. They could easily prove that they would have paid you at the end of your probation, but you broke the bond and absconded!

In conclusion you have the following options:

1) Talk to the old employer and ask whether it would be possible for them to issue the letter after you paid the bond amount. This would work if you are in a position to pay the amount. You could also ask this amount as sign-on bonus from your next employer(if they agree).

2) Let the HR of the next organization know what really happened. As mentioned before, they don't want to maintain a file of your documents, they need it for BGC. Maybe other documents like your salary slips for that period can suffice.

Comment: Wouldn't offering to pay the bond amount after the company withheld incentives be rewarding bad behavior?

Comment: @jcm I agree but at this point, moving on ahead in his career is more important to the OP. It would be difficult to convince large organizations to offer employment without relieving letter. Sadly this is the established norm in in India

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to get into legal things, and want to get my relieving
>   letter happily.

Well thats not going to work for you, since you've essentially broken the bond and walked away from them. It may very well be that they owe you nothing, and that you won't get a relieving letter from them.

Maybe you can use old payslips or documentation that you worked there to prove that you in fact did?